# Simul8 two queues with one mandatory for part of population and optional for the remaining

Tags: simulation

In Simul8, anyone know how to set up a model that has two queues A and B. 20% of the entering population must use queue B and the remaining 80% can use the one with less queue.

I currently have set it up forcing 20% to use A and 80% to use B, but need to change it as I described.

Any one knows how to do this?